# why this class not compiling?

Tags: java, class, variables, scope

Why is this error coming?  Please see the following code.

```
class Test{
  Hello h=new Hello();
}

class Hello{
  int a=10;
  System.out.println(a);   // error identifier expected
}
```

Comment: How do you expect this to even run with no main method?

Comment: A lot of things wrong with this. No main() function. A System.out function without any block. Make  a main() function in  Test and put System out statement in static after making a as static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Class With Same Package

```
public class Hello {

    public void print(){

        int a = 10;
        System.out.println("Number is :" +a);
    }
}
```

Crate Class to Set the Main Method Within the Same Package of Hello Method

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Hello h1 =  new Hello();
        h1.print();
    }
}
```